# Use Connections of LinqPad to instantiate an ObjectContext/DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, database-connection, connection-string, linqpad, objectcontext

I have defined 2 diffrent Connections (named like "Connection1" and "Connection2") using `EntityFramework (ObjectContext)`  in LinqPad.

When i now define a Query (Statement or Programm) in LinqPad, i have to choose a Connection from the ComboBox that i would like to use for the Query.

Lets say I select the Connection "Connection1" i can now write queries against the Context and execute them, but i also need to use an ObjectContext that used the "Connection2".

Is it possible to use the Connections that i specify in LinqPad to use as ConnectionString to instantiate a new ObjectContext or is there a factory in LinqPad to create a EntityConnection.

Example:

```
Connection2Container context = new Connection2Container("Connection2");
// or
EntityConnection connection = LinqPadFactory.CreateEntityConnection("Connection2");
Connection2Container context = new Connection2Container(connection);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is totally possible.

There are 2 "standard" approaches to this.

1. Choose the connection you want to use as a primary connection. Then hold down the `ctrl` key while dragging the second/third/n-th connection from the schema overview on the left into the query window.
   After this you'll have to use a slight different syntax to access your entities

   ```
   Connection1.Persons.Where(x=> ....)

   Connction2.OrderDetails.Join(...)
   ```
2. Click add new Linq-To-Sql Connection. Click "Include additional databases" Go.

As far as I am aware, this is only available on Linqpad Premium (maybe Pro, too). I am using the Premium version, so I can't give you a hands-on check on the pro version.

Kind regards.

Comment: I´m also using the Premium edition of LinqPad. What you describe does not work for me. I´m using Entity Framework. Maybe the steps you describe work for Linq-To-Sql

Answer (score 1):

You can add the assemblies that contain your ObjectContexts as references. Open the Query Properties (press <kbd>F4</kbd>), and click *Browse...* button when viewing the *Additional References* tab to pull in your assemblies. Now you can use your ObjectContexts like you would from any .NET project.